# Why is the profile not showing a deleted post?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Now I can see deleted posts.

How can I see deleted post from a specific user?

The profile-page of a user is not showing that. Why?

Comment: You can only search/list for your own deleted posts. but if you come across a direct link to a deleted post, you can view it with that privilege.

Answer (score 8):

> how can I see deleted post from an specific user...

You'll need to be elected as a moderator, or be hired as an SE staff member.

> the profile-page of a user not showing that, why?

You don't have the moderation privilege.